# Linker errors when using OpenGL in Qt

Tags: qt, visual-c++, opengl, linker

I am trying to use OpenGL with Qt.
I was following this example: http://qt-project.org/doc/qt-5.0/qtgui/openglwindow.html using Qt 5 build for msvc2012. In the end I am getting the following errors:

1. error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_glClear@4 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall OpenGLWindow::render(void)" (?render@OpenGLWindow@@UAEXXZ)   D:\Documents\Code\Qt Projects\qttest2\qttest2\openglwindow.obj  qttest2
2. error LNK2001: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_glClear@4  D:\Documents\Code\Qt Projects\qttest2\qttest2\trianglewindow.obj    qttest2
3. error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_glDrawArrays@12 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall TriangleWindow::render(void)" (?render@TriangleWindow@@UAEXXZ) D:\Documents\Code\Qt Projects\qttest2\qttest2\trianglewindow.obj    qttest2
4. error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol _*imp*_glViewport@16 referenced in function "public: virtual void __thiscall TriangleWindow::render(void)" (?render@TriangleWindow@@UAEXXZ)   D:\Documents\Code\Qt Projects\qttest2\qttest2\trianglewindow.obj    qttest2
5. error LNK1120: 3 unresolved externals   D:\Documents\Code\Qt Projects\qttest2\Win32\Debug\qttest2.exe  qttest2

I can see that it has to do with the linking of OpenGL functions but I don't have much knowledge about linking.

I get the errors even if I copy the source code in from the OpenGLWindow example.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You must add `opengl32.lib` to the list of linked libraries. Adding the OpenGL module in the QtCreator .pro file should do the trick

```
QT += opengl
```

Comment: Thank you datenwolf! I thought that the Qt project template took care of that when Gtgui was used but apparently not.

Comment: Do you know if the .pro files are used when using the Qt visual studio plug-in? As I understand it, .pro files have to do with the QtCreator application.

Comment: @MHA: Of course in Visual Studio you must use the Compiler/Linker settings of that one. Qt is separated in several libraries, one of them is qtopengl.{so,dll}, so you must add that, namely the linker file, i.e. qtopengl.lib, and opengl32.lib (or libGL.so) to it. (Or whatever the DLL/LIB is called exactly. I normally use CMake and the Qt CMake module does all the heavy lifting for me :P)

Comment: Hi can you please clarify your post? I have the same problem but adding "opengl" to the .pro file did not do the trick. I am using MSVC2013 as my compiler. How do I link these libraries to it?

Comment: @user929404: First you must make sure, that you have a Qt5 build that actually supports OpenGL. The default pre-built Qt5 packages for MSVC are built without OpenGL support and internally use ANGLE for QtQuick. http://qt-project.org/forums/viewreply/107114/

Comment: @datenwolf Thank you. I did compile Qt 5 for this purpose. OpenGL is working for me using the Visual Studio plugin. For QtCreator, I cannot get over linker errors (they point to the constructor and destructor of my class that extends QGlWidget)

Answer (score 2):

Have you added the OpenGL module in your pro file like this:

```
QT += opengl
```

Comment: I added opengl32.lib to the list of linked libraries, which is the visual studio equivalent. Thank you for the answer! I marked datenwolf's reply as the answer since I think he was first.

Comment: @MHA Please can you explain how you "added opengl32.lib" to the list of linked libraries. I am using MSVC2013 as my compiler with Qt Creator

Comment: Sadly no. It has been a while since I worked with this problem (almost a year). You better seek the solution elsewhere :) Good luck!

Answer (score 2):

If you use Qt 5, then add next lib in you project file (*.pro)

```
LIBS += -LD:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\lib\libQt5OpenGL.a -lopengl32
```

`D:\Qt\5.5\mingw492_32\lib\libQt5OpenGL.a` is path.

Answer (score 0):

In linux environment [mesa] library installation can resolve the issue.
[lib32-mesa, an open-source implementation of the OpenGL specification]

```
[pacman -S mesa ]       *Arch Linux 
[apt-get install mesa]  *ubuntu/Mint/Raspbian
```

Comment: That was an idea, to help developers looking for solution.